# Is the self-shunt pattern the same as stubbing in TDD?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am reading the book TDD by Example and one of the patterns demonstrated was the self-shunt pattern.

Basically, if I am not mistaken, if I have a test like this:

```js
test("list of users should receive a new user"), () => {
  const user = new User()
  const listOfUsers = new ListOfUsers()
  listOfUsers.insert(user)
}
```

Then, the only way to know if `listOfUsers` actually received the user, is to stub it, correct?

```
class ListOfUsersStub {
  constructor () {
    this.users = []
  }

  insert (user) {
    this.users.push(user)
    return this.users
  }
}
```

then I can test it so:

```js
test("list of users should receive a new user"), () => {
  const user = new User()
  const listOfUsers = new ListOfUsersStub()
  const result = listOfUsers.insert(user)
  expect(result.users).toContain(user)
}
```

Is this the same as the self shunt pattern? Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: *"the only way to know if listOfUsers actually received the user, is to stub it, correct?"* - if `listOfUsers` is designed reasonably and provides a way to retrieve the objects it contains, then the answer is **no, that's plain wrong**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your example does not show the self-shunt pattern.

The self-shunt pattern can only be implemented with testing frameworks where the testcases are either a class or a method within an explicitly defined class. The bottom-line is that *you* must write that class. It cannot come from the testing framework.

A second requirement for the self-shunt pattern is that the code-under-test wants to use a dependency that can be injected. In the self-shunt pattern, it is the testcase class itself, augmented to implement the right interface, that gets injected for that dependency.

---

> Then, the only way to know if `listOfUsers` actually received the user, is to stub it, correct?

No. And most emphatically no if `ListOfUsers` is the class you are actually testing.

With a stub, you replace a class that does something complicated, time-consuming or otherwise problematic for stable, repeatable tests with a class that just returns canned answers according to your testing needs. You **do not** want to do such a replacement of the very code you are trying to establish of that is works correctly.

The correct way to know in insertion into `listOfUsers` worked is to check if `listOfUsers` contains the new element. This is one example why the unit you are testing is the entire class, rather than a single method and why a unittest can call multiple methods of a class and still be properly called a unittest.